# Cannot insert duplicate key in object in seed method when linking two objects in 1 to * association

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I get this problem n-th time in 4 year period and never have I found a explanation and solution why it works this way.

I've got 2 classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Survey Survey { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}
public class Answer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public String Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Then in Seed method I want to create questions and answers and link them together:

```
        Guid guid23 = new Guid("c2c6900a-c8a7-4a4b-aa65-79cd0317f9d1");
        //some other guids ...
Survey survey1 = new Survey { Id = guid21, Title = "Cars" };
        Survey survey2 = new Survey { Id = guid22, Title = "Phones" };

        Question question1 = new Question { Id = guid23, Text = "What type of car do you have?" };
        Question question2 = new Question { Id = guid24, Text = "What size is the engine?" };
        Question question3 = new Question { Id = guid25, Text = "What phone do you have?" };
        Question question4 = new Question { Id = guid26, Text = "What big is the screen?" };

        Answer answer1 = new Answer { Id = guid27, Text = "Sedan"};
        Answer answer2 = new Answer { Id = guid28, Text = "3000" };


        context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id, question1, question2, question3, question4);
        context.Answers.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id, answer1, answer2);
        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Answers.Find(answer1.Id).Question = question1;
        context.Answers.Find(answer2.Id).Question = question2;
        context.SaveChanges();
```

Then when I run `database update -v` I get:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_dbo.Questions'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.Questions'. The duplicate key value is
>   (c2c6900a-c8a7-4a4b-aa65-79cd0317f9d1). The statement has been
>   terminated.

How to link two objects in one to many association in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a [known bug in `AddOrUpdate`](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6/issues/23). Here's what happens.

The start situation is that you've already got the questions and answers in the database.

The first `AddOrUpdate`...

```
context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(a => a.Id, question1, question2,...
```

...finds the questions and attaches them to the context as `UnChanged`. However, the actually found instances are not the same as `question1, question2,...`. The found instances are new objects that are hidden inside the context. The instances `question1, question2,...` are `Detached`!

Therefore, the statement...

```
context.Answers.Find(answer1.Id).Question = question1;
```

...connects `answer1` to a question instance that's completely new to the context. After the statement `question1`'s state is `Added` and `SaveChanges` will try to insert a new question under an existing `Id`.

You were already close to the fix. You seem to have been aware of this issue to some extent, because you already use `context.Answers.Find(answer1.Id)`. This statement pulls the hidden `answer1` counterpart from the context's cache, so EF doesn't see *that* one as new. The fix is to do the same with the questions:

```
question1 = context.Questions.Find(question1.Id);
question2 = context.Questions.Find(question2.Id);

context.Answers.Find(answer1.Id).Question = question1;
context.Answers.Find(answer2.Id).Question = question2;
context.SaveChanges();
```